# Meaning of "Diffusion Rate"

Tags: mixtures

A friend is trying to understand a paper which discusses the diffusion of proteins through milk. Rather than listing a diffusivity (with units [Length]^2/[Time]), the paper lists the 'diffusion rate' of the proteins through the liquid, in units of mm/hr (i.e. [Length]/[Time]).

We can't make heads or tails of this. I was wondering about some sort of 'average front propagation velocity', but I'm not sure how that would be defined, as a diffusion front's velocity can change over time, and depends on the geometry, concentrations, etc.

Has anyone run into this terminology before?

Thanks

Comment: In the attached pdf (page 7, part C) the diffusion of a dye is measured as the liner distance the drop of dye solution penetrates into a test tube of gelatin. http://www.instruction.greenriver.edu/kmarr/biology%20211/Labs%20and%20ALEs/B211%20Labs/B211%20Labs/4_Lab%204_DiffusnOsmosis_B211_Fall2009.pdf // There must be some sort of experiment where the diffusion was measured in some sort of linear manner...

Comment: Could you give information on the paper? It might make the question easier to answer for anyone with access.